# Force IE8 emulation in IE10 iframe

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-10, x-ua-compatible

My company recently migrated from IE8 to IE10
I need to emulate IE8 in order to display page properly in IE10

This is the structure of my page:
[image: Page structure]

I want main page and iframe to render in IE8 mode, but only main page is rendered in IE8 mode (content in iframe is rendered in IE10 mode). In both main page and iframe content I have:

```
tag <!doctype html> and metadata X-UA-Comapatible: IE=EmulateIE8
```

If I run content of iframe separamelly it is rendered in IE8 mode.

How to force IE10 to use IE8 mode also in iframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "emulate" values tell IE to follow the default behavior; that is, to use the mode it would normally use based on the document type declaration (doctype).

Since you're using the HTML5 doctype, this would lead IE to choose edge mode, the latest and greatest mode available to that version of IE.

To restrict things to a specific mode, specify that in your content attribute value, e.g. `content="ie=8"`

Note that you may need to do this for both the parent and the child iframe.  (There's a specific set of parsing rules in certain versions that allow you to mix standards modes, but that's even more confusing, so it's best to be consistent throughout.)

See [Specifying legacy document modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx) for more info.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance